# Proving that $\nabla u$ is not bounded near $x=0$ for the Dirichlet problem for the half-space

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, boundary-value-problem

So I am trying to solve a problem from Evan's book, which asks to prove that $\nabla u$ is *not* bounded near $x=0$, where $u$ is the solution of 
$$\begin{cases} \Delta u = 0 & \text{in } \mathbb{R}_+^n\\
u = g & \text{on } \partial\mathbb{R}_+^n \end{cases}$$
where $\mathbb{R}_+^n = \{(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n: x_n>0\}$ and $g$ is bounded and $g(x) = |x|$ for $|x|\leq 1$.

I found this solution in http://users.math.msu.edu/users/kpromisl/math849/HW2A.pdf which I was able to follow because it is very clear, but one thing stroke me as odd. They separate $\frac{u(\lambda e_n) - u(0)}{\lambda}$ as the addition of two integrals, and then argue that one of those integrals is convergent and therefore finite for any $\lambda$, while the other is divergent for any $\lambda$.

But wouldn't that mean that $u(\lambda e_n) = \infty$ for any $\lambda > 0$? But how can that be if $u$ is supposed to be well-defined in $\mathbb{R}_+^n$, which obviously includes any $x = \lambda e_n$ for $\lambda > 0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why they claim that $J$ is divergent. But what seems to be true is that $J$ tends to $+\infty$ when $\lambda \to 0$. And we can conclude from that.

EDIT: to be more precise $r^{n-1}/(\lambda^2+r^2)^{n/2}$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ (because $\lambda>0$) so $J$ is convergent. But when $\lambda \to 0$ then $r^{n-1}/(\lambda^2+r^2)^{n/2} \sim 1/r$ so we get an divergent integral.

Comment: I don't know, I used Mathematica and it seems like J is indeed divergent for any $\lambda > 0$. I fixed randomly chosen values for $\lambda$ (small and big), and then computed the integral $J$ with r from $r=1$ to $r=R$, and when the larger I choose R, the larger the integral seems to become and without any apparent bound.

Comment: Oh wait never mind!!! $J$ is in the unit ball, so it should be from $r=0$ to $r=1$, and that is indeed convergent like you explained (and it checks out in Mathematica :P). Ok, so my initial concern was valid: $u$ is well defined for $x=\lambda e_n$, the authors just made a small oversight, but otherwise their argument is perfectly valid as long as we take $\lambda \to 0$.